# CMake cannot find include libpq-fe.h

Tags: postgresql, cmake, mingw32, mingw-w64

I'm trying to build a program which requieres `libpq-fe.h` include file.

This file is in `E:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\pgsql\include`

In my CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
# declare project
PROJECT(localscp)

set(pg_SOURCE_DIR /usr/local/pgsql)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  "E:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/psql/include"
)

# declare executables
ADD_EXECUTABLE(localscp localscp.cc)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(localscp 
  dl pthread z pq)
```

When I do `cmake .` I get:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/informemedico/localscp
```

When I do `mingw32-make` I get:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/localscp.dir/localscp.cc.obj
E:\informemedico\localscp\localscp.cc:24:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\localscp.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/localscp.dir/localscp.cc.obj' failed
mingw32-make[6]: *** [CMakeFiles/localscp.dir/localscp.cc.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/localscp.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[5]: *** [CMakeFiles/localscp.dir/all] Error 2
makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why the compiler can't find that include file?.

Comment: What's in your C++ file? probably not just `#include <libpq-fe.h>`, right? Usually you use `find_package(PostgreSQL)` or however it is named. Then you can simply add the includes and libraries to your target.

Comment: In you CMakeLists.txt directory component is `psql`, but should be `pgsql`.

Comment: Thanks! @Tsyvarev what stupid I am. Please add your comment as an answer to let me mark as correct.

Comment: SO doesn't store questions, which decision requires only to fix misprints. It helps you, and it is sufficient.